# Why do I have to specify DNS when using chroot?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, chroot

Last time when I chrooted from Live USB to my old broken system, I couldn't connect to Internet. In this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure), I read I should add OpenDNS to my `/etc/resolv.conf` **if I use DHCP**.

**How does DHCP (or chroot) influence my DNS?**

Isn't DHCP only a way for my router to give me an IP?
Why can I connect from Live USB to Internet normally, while in `chroot` I have to add new DNS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't DHCP only the way my router gives me IP?

No, it's also the way your router gives you extra information – gateway IP, DNS server IP, default domain name, time server IP, et cetera.

> Why I can connect from Live USB to Internet normally, while in chroot I have to add new DNS?

Linux stores the DNS server address in a file. Since chroot alters how programs see file paths, it means they'll find a different file at the `/etc/resolv.conf` path, which means they'll possibly find a different address stored there.

(Your DHCP client doesn't know anything about your chroots, and only updates the *main* `/etc/resolv.conf` file – it cannot search and update *all* possible files.)

---

A common workaround is to link (bind) the "inside" path so that it refers to the same "outside" file. For example, you can do this before chrooting to /mnt:

```
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

(Of course, later you'll have to unmount this before the system will let you unmount /mnt.)

Comment: If your `resolv.conf` is a symlink (or you don't want it to muck with the original), use `cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /path/to/etc`.